# How to use || or && in Email Template or PDF Template Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf

I want to use || in {{if}}

I tryed like this but it not work, please help me

```
{{if helper.eq(order.shipping_description, "abcd") || helper.eq(order.shipping_description, "dede") }}
<p>abcd & dede</p>
{{else}}
<p>Not abcd & dede</p>
{{/if}}
```

It only work with `helper.eq(order.shipping_description, "abcd")`, not work with `helper.eq(order.shipping_description, "dede")`

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong on this, but I don't think the `{{if}}` directive works with conditions like `varName == "varValue"`.
I wasn't able to find int he core any use like this.
I think it only works with

```
{{if varName}}
    text shown when varName evaluates to true
{{else}}
    text shown when varName evaluates to false
{{/if}}
```

You can check how everything works, but debugging the method `\Magento\Framework\Filter\Template::ifDirective`.

But I may have a solution for your problem.
I assume the `helper` variable is something custom that you can control.
You can get rid of the `if` directive, but doing the checks in your helper class.

Here is an example:

```
public function getShippingDescriptionMessage($order)
{
    $description = $order->getShippingDescription();
    if ($description === 'abcd' || $description === 'dede') {
        return __('abcd & dede');
    }
    return __('Not abcd & dede');
}
```

then replace your whole `{{if}}{{else}}{{/if}}` directive with

```
{{var helper.getShippingDescriptionMessage($order)}}
```

Note: Haven't tested this. But it looks like it may work